# Where can I find the code to modify the stock Android dialer in Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-source

I want to change the SIP registration timeout value in the default android Dialer, as well as route all calls through cell instead of SIP.

I am looking in 5.0.0_r2 tree, and under packages/apps/Dialer, I can't find any appropriate source code.

packages/apps/Phone is empty.

Does this mean Google has closed source for the android Dialer? How come it's working in the emulator?

Comment: See if you can find any relevant logs in the emulator, then grep the source for those tags or messages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Damn. It would appear that indeed Google has closed the source to Dialer starting a few releases ago, as the one in the emulator is quite basic in functionality.

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to the question and is outdated.

Answer (score 3):

Source for the Dialer app can be found here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/